# Error while loading md-table (Angular Material Design Table)

Tags: angular, typescript, material-design

I am trying to integrate  Angular Material table (https://material.angular.io/components/table) into my Angular Application.

I have created the Angular App using CLI and my table declaration is as follows.

```
<md-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource">

    <!--- Note that these columns can be defined in any order.
      The actual rendered columns are set as a property on the row definition" -->

    <!-- ID Column -->
    <ng-container cdkColumnDef="userId">
        <md-header-cell *cdkHeaderCellDef> ID </md-header-cell>
        <md-cell *cdkCellDef="let row"> {{row.id}} </md-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Progress Column -->
    <ng-container cdkColumnDef="progress">
        <md-header-cell *cdkHeaderCellDef> Progress </md-header-cell>
        <md-cell *cdkCellDef="let row"> {{row.progress}}% </md-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Name Column -->
    <ng-container cdkColumnDef="userName">
        <md-header-cell *cdkHeaderCellDef> Name </md-header-cell>
        <md-cell *cdkCellDef="let row"> {{row.name}} </md-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Color Column -->
    <ng-container cdkColumnDef="color">
        <md-header-cell *cdkHeaderCellDef> Color </md-header-cell>
        <md-cell *cdkCellDef="let row" [style.color]="row.color"> {{row.color}} </md-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <md-header-row *cdkHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></md-header-row>
    <md-row *cdkRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></md-row>
</md-table>
```

And has initiated it as follows..

```
public onInit(): void {
        this.dataSource = new ExampleDataSource(this.exampleDatabase);
```

But I get the following error..

> compiler.es5.js:1690 Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
>   Can't bind to 'dataSource' since it isn't a known property of 'md-table'.
>   1. If 'md-table' is an Angular component and it has 'dataSource' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
>   2. If 'md-table' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
>   3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("lipsis_sm no-margin">{{localizationService.language.MF_CHART_FOOTER_DES}}
>
> ][dataSource]="dataSource">
>
> 'md-header-cell' is not a known element:
>   1. If 'md-header-cell' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
>   2. If 'md-header-cell' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("

I have used [this](https://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview) plunker to help me with the integration.

What could be the reason?

I have used following dependencies..

```
"@angular/animations": "^4.3.0",
"@angular/cdk": "^2.0.0-beta.8",
"@angular/common": "^4.3.0",
"@angular/compiler": "^4.3.0",
"@angular/core": "^4.3.0",
"@angular/forms": "^4.2.6",
"@angular/http": "^4.2.6",
"@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.8",
```

Your help is appreciated..

Thanks !

Edit 1:

I created a new project and still the material components are not taken.

https://github.com/newair/Angular-Material-Test

What could be the reason?

Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
'md-button' is not a known element:
1. If 'md-button' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'md-button' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("

Help is much appreciated..!!

Thanks ..!!

Comment: Did you import datasource? Like `import {DataSource} from '@angular/cdk';`

Comment: Would you mind sharing the rest of the ts code of your component? You might be missing something

Comment: I have made the Edit 1 in Original post. Seems I get the same error in a new project as well.

Comment: So the problem right now is that md-button should be used like this: `<button md-button>foo</button>`, not `<md-button></md-button>`. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Ana its my bad. Problem was that I had used them inside the components which were used by sub modules ( other modules that were imported to app.module) . And I have only imported them to root app.module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you include `MdTableModule` and `CdkTableModule` in your app's imports.

Note that `<md-button></md-button>` is not valid because `MdButton` uses an attribute selector. Instead, try `<button md-button> My Button </button>`

Comment: Thanks Andrew. Your answer helped me.